# Does new X cause a mem leak when passed as an argument to a function?

Tags: c++

Definition of **ReadProcessMemory()**:

```
ReadProcessMemory(HANDLE hProcess, LPCVOID lpBaseAddress, LPVOID lpBuffer, 
                  nSize, SIZE_T * lpNumberOfBytesRead);
```

Are there any problems doing it like this?

```
ReadProcessMemory(this->processHandle, 0, &ret, sizeof(int), new DWORD);
```

Comment: Yes, it's a memory leak.

Comment: Depends on what `ReadProcessMemory` does, but probably yes. Have you read a C++ book? If not, please do so, learning C++ by trial and error won't work, trust me.

Comment: Can you explain, why do have any doubts about this?

Comment: Using `new DWORD` for an argument of type `SIZE_T*` looks quite fishy from the types alone btw. I *strongly* recommend reading a C++ book.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are problems.

You will not be able to determine how many bytes were read, because you don't have access to that value, because the temporary pointer was lost.

And you will never be able to free the `DWORD` object, so you have a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have a memory leak. You will not be able to recover the address of your new `DWORD` to delete it. The correct usage for this function is to provide the address of an existing `DWORD` and then to read it.

```
DWORD bytesRead;
ReadProcessMemory(this->processHandle, 0, &ret, sizeof(int), &bytesRead);
// bytesRead can be read to see how many bytes were read
```

It would be strange, but not impossible, that a function would accept a pointer to a new variable and then delete it internally. Make sure to read the documentation attentively when using a library or API.

Comment: It would also be strange, but not impossible, for the function to communicate the value of the argument in some way so that the caller can deallocate it.